# Looking for a way to highlight specific words in textareas?

Tags: java, swing, text, textarea

Hi i'm looking for a way to highlight specific words in text kind of like how a text editor might work with syntax highlighting. The highlighting will consist of the text being different colours and/or different styles such as italic, bold or regular.

In order to narrow focus, how this might be achieved using Java Swing components.

There are most probably a number of ways of doing this but one that is efficient in dealing with multiple highlighted words and large amounts of text.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Java's [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) class: it does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Highlighter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html) that is available through JTextComponent's setHighlighter().

Answer (score 1):

I would use a JTextPane. Its easier to use than a JEditorPane as you don't have to know or worry about HTML. The link you where given to the Swing tutorial covers both components.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rtext/). I personally like it because:
 - it's easy extendable
 - it comes with really useful plugins
 - opensource & free & maintained
 - it supports bunch of languages like: C, Java, Ruby, Php, HTML, CSS, Sql and so on.